# "google account: sign-in attempt blocked" response using apache ant mail task

Tags: ant, gmail

I run unit tests on code I am writing using Apache Ant, ant.apache.org.  A few months ago, I set up an Ant mail task to send the results of the unit tests using gmail as an smtp server.

```
<mail

     user="e-mail address"

     password="password"

     ssl="yes"

     mailhost="smtp.gmail.com"

     mailport="465"

     subject="Nightly unit test results">

     <to address="e-mail address" />

     <from address="e-mail address" />

     <message src="/Directory/On/My/Machine" /></mail>
```

When I first started, this worked. These days, I get an error from gmail saying my sign-in attempt has been blocked.  Can someone tell me if there is something I need to change in the mail task, or do I need to loosen the security settings on my gmail account?  If possible, I'd prefer to not do the latter.  I have contacted ant.apache.org and have not received any answers from them.

Thanks,

Jason Mazzotta

Answer (score 0):

I posted this same question to the Arstechnica forums and got this link, which works:

http://ellisbenus.com/web-design-columbia-mo/workaround-using-gmail-alias-forwarded-email-addresses/